# Find in a text all words that appear 10 or more times

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, sort

I am given a txt file (war and peace..), and i need to create a text file sorted alphabetically of all the words that appear 10 or more times (without the quantity).

The twist in this question, is that every punctuation is considered as a beginning of a new word, meaning you're is considered two words, you re.

I flipped all punctuation into new lines, and all spaces to new lines. And i used trim -c so now i have all words and their count, don't know how to show only those that appear 10 or more times.

Any help regarding a way to find all words that appear 10 or more times would be really appreciated!

Comment: Solve your homework yourself!

Comment: I flipped all punct for new lines, and all spaces to new lines. trimmed it (so now i have all words in the text, and i know how much each one appears.
What I don't know is from this state how to only show those that appear 10 or more times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
< text tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' |
  awk '++count[$0] == 10' |
  sort
```

Replace `$0` with `tolower($0)` if you want to ignore case.

That **tr**anslates **s**equences of characters that are the **c**omplement of the **al**pha**num**erical ones to **n**ewlines. `awk` prints the 10th occurrence of each.

Note that [on GNU systems, `tr` doesn't work properly on multi-byte characters](/q/228558). However, on those systems, you can use GNU `grep`'s `-o` extension instead:

```
< text grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+' |
  awk '++count[$0] == 10' |
  sort
```

You can change that to

```
< text grep -Eo '[^[:punct:][:space:]]+' |
  awk '++count[$0] == 10' |
  sort
```

to consider characters that are neither **punct**uation nor **space** (or `tr -s '[:punct:][:space:]' '[\n*]'` above for non-GNU system or all-ASCII text) which on [that War and Peace text](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2600/2600-0.txt) gives the same result.

Note that on GNU systems at least, that could still give wrong results as Unicode combining accents for instance are classified as *punctuation* and not *alnums* (they don't appear in that text though where the accented characters are in their combined form).

Answer (score 2):

In case you have already stripped dots and white-spaces from the file and only have the words in it, as mentioned in your comments (no extra white-spaces/tabs), then you can use `sort`,`uniq` and `awk` to get what you wanted :

```
sort file_with_words | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 >= 10) { print}}'
```

My solution only works if the file is properly formatted (one word / line, no extra spaces/tabs).

Answer (score 1):

In perl :

```
perl -e 'while(<>){while(/([[:alpha:]]+)/g){$c{$&}++}};foreach $w(keys %c){if($c{$w}<10){delete $c{$w}}};foreach $w(sort keys %c){print "$w\n"}' WarAndPeace.txt
```

Indented :

```
perl -e '# Let s count every words
         while(<>){
             while(/([[:alpha:]]+)/g){
                 $c{$&}++
             }
          }
          # Let s remove lesser than 10
          foreach $w(keys %c){
              if($c{$w}<10){
                  delete $c{$w}
              }
          }
          # Let s sort and print
          foreach $w(sort keys %c){
              print "$w\n"
          }' WarAndPeace.txt
```

With UTF-8 :

```
 perl -e 'use open qw/:std :utf8/;
          # Let s count every words
             while(<>){
                 while(/([[:alpha:]]+)/g){
                     $c{$&}++
                 }
              }
              # Let s remove lesser than 10
              foreach $w(keys %c){
                  if($c{$w}<10){
                      delete $c{$w}
                  }
              }
              # Let s sort and print
              foreach $w(sort keys %c){
                  print "$w\n"
              }' WarAndPeace.txt
```

Comment: I just added the needed command for utf-8